# Number of ways to add multiples of numbers from a set of k numbers while all numbers are never multiplied.

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to come up with a general formula. First let me give a simple example.

## Let there be 3 numbers: a, b, and c.

I multiply any two of them to get:

## 1. a*b

## 2. b*c

## 3. c*a .......[A]

Exactly three ways to multiply any two of them. Right!
Next I add any two of above without repetition. I get:

## 4. a*b + b*c

## 5. a*b + c*a

## 6. b*c + c*a

Hence I get 3 combinations. Please observe that I added the a*b to all the multiples in [A] until I exhausted all the combinations. Only then I chose b*c. 
Next I add all of the results in [A] to get:

## 7. a*b + b*c + c*a

Now I stop. In total, I get 7 combinations.

## Let me try with 4 numbers, say a, b, c, and d.

There are four ways to multiply any three of four numbers. Right! I multiply any three of four numbers to get:

## 1. a*b*c

## 2. b*c*d

## 3. c*d*a

## 4. d*a*b   ......[B]

Next I add any two of above without repetition. I get:

## 5. a*b*c + b*c*d

## 6. a*b*c + c*d*a

## 7. a*b*c + d*a*b

## 8. b*c*d + c*d*a

## 9. b*c*d + d*a*b

## 10. c*d*a + d*a*b

Hence I get 6 combinations. Please observe that I added a*b*c to all the multiples until I exhausted all the combinations. Only then I chose b*c*d and later c*d*a.
Next I add any 3 in [B] to get:

## 11. a*b*c + b*c*d + c*d*a

## 12. a*b*c + b*c*d + d*a*b

## 13. a*b*c + c*d*a + d*a*b

## 14. b*c*d + c*d*a + d*a*b

I get 4 such additions. No more. Right!
Lastly I add all four in [B] to get:

## 15. a*b*c + b*c*d + c*d*a + d*a*b

Now I stop. In total, I get 15 combinations with 4 numbers.

## Now I am trying with a set of k numbers.

## I can multiply any of (k-1) numbers in the set to get exactly k multiples. Hence k combinations.

Next I choose the first multiple and add it to remaining (k-1) multiples to get (k-1) combinations for addition. I already got all the possible additions with the first multiple. So I strike out the first multiple. Now I chose the second multiple and add it to remaining (k-2) multiples to get (k-2) combinations of addition. Now I strike out the second multiple. I continue with the remaining (k-3) multiples and so on..

## I get following number of combinations: (k-1) + (k-2) + (k-3) + ... + (k - (k-1)) = k*(k - 1) - (1 + 2 + 3 + ... + (k-1)) = k*(k - 1) - (Sum of (k-1) natural numbers) = k*(k-1) - (k-1)*k/2 = k*(k-1)/2

Next I need to choose any 3 multiples non repetitively and find their combinations until I have added all the k multiples.

## How could I arrive at some formula that could give me the total number of combinations with k numbers right away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you choose $(k-1)$ numbers out of $k$
$${k \choose k-1}$$
Now out of the ${k \choose k-1}$ numbers you choose n of them where n is a number between 1 and ${k \choose k-1}$, You add up all the possibilities for n.

This will be the final formula
$\sum_1^{k \choose k-1}{{k \choose k-1}\choose n}$

Comment: The last expression can be simplified to $2^{\binom{k-1}{k}}-1$